# Substituindo for pela função Lapply no R

Tags: r

Essa é a minha lista

```
lista1<-list(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10), c(11, 12, 13, 14, 15
), c(16, 17, 18, 19, 20), c(21, 22, 23, 24, 25))
```

Construo uma lista nova da maneira abaixo.

```
novalista <- vector(mode = "list", length=5)

for (i in 1:5) {
  for(k in 1:5) {     
    novalista[[i]][k] <- lista1[[i]][k]*8
  }
}

novalista
```

Estu querendo fazer um codigo mais simples/limpo utilizando a funcao lapply. Ou seja, quero substituir esses dois "for´s" pela funçaõ lapply.

A dificuldade é usar a funcao lapply com dois indices diferentes (i e k)

Alguma ajuda?

Answer (score 4):

Em primeiro lugar, o R é uma linguagem de programação vetorizada. Isso significa que o duplo ciclo `for` não é necessário. Como cada membro da `lista1` é um vetor, pode-se multiplicar o vetor inteiro por 8.

```
for (i in 1:5) {
    novalista[[i]] <- lista1[[i]]*8
}
```

E o código já está mais simples e rápido.

No caso do exemplo da pergunta, pode-se fazer ainda melhor.
O que a pergunta pretende é aplicar uma função a cada membro da lista `lista1`, ora é exatamente isso que o `lapply` faz. **Não é preciso indexar os membros da lista**. Basta aplicar a função diretamente a cada um deles. É ainda preciso ter em conta que o `lapply` não elimina o ciclo, o `lapply` é també uma forma de ciclo.

```
novalista2 <- lapply(lista1, '*', 8)

identical(novalista, novalista2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Aqui a função é a multiplicação, `*`, com o argumento extra `8`, o multiplicador.

Isto dá quase sempre código mais simples mas ao contrário do que muitos usuários do R pensam, nem sempre é mais rápido. Para testar isso vou usar o pacote `microbenchmark`. Os dois modos de criar a `novalista` são escritos em forma de função e depois testados.

```
f <- function(lst){
    novalista <- vector(mode = "list", length=length(lst))
    for (i in seq_along(lst)) {
        novalista[[i]] <- lst[[i]]*8
    }
    novalista
}

g <- function(lst) lapply(lst, '*', 8)
```

Primeiro com a pequena lista da pergunta.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f(lista1), g(lista1), times = 1e4)
```

Agora com uma lista grande.

```
lista2 <- lapply(1:1000, function(i) sample(1000, 100))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f(lista2), g(lista2))
```

Como se pode ver, em ambos os casos o `for` foi mais rápido.

Comment: Muito obrigada! A minha duvida era entender como o lapply "entenderia" a a prioridade que o for "de dentro do loop" tem. Pq ele só volta para o for que se inicia no i quando termina o for que inicia no k. Como funciona esssa etapa no lapply?

Answer (score 1):

Execute:

```
lista1<-list(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10), c(11, 12, 13, 14, 15
), c(16, 17, 18, 19, 20), c(21, 22, 23, 24, 25))

novalista<-lapply(lista1,'*',8)
novalista

#[[1]]
#[1]  8 16 24 32 40

#[[2]]
#[1] 48 56 64 72 80

#[[3]]
#[1]  88  96 104 112 120

#[[4]]
#[1] 128 136 144 152 160

#[[5]]
#[1] 168 176 184 192 200
```